# GCC equivalent of armclang --target=aarch64-arm-none-eabi compiler option

Tags: gcc, arm, arm64, armv8, armclang

Hi I am trying to find out the GCC equivalent of armclang compiler option --target=aarch64-arm-none-eabi which instructs the compiler to generate A64 instructions?

Comment: You probably need to get a specific version of GCC that has been built to target that ABI.

Comment: If you want to build for aarch64, there is GCC toolchain intended for that. Different toolchains also depending on type of OS you are gonna build for, Win, Linux, none. https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads